# How do I match a numeric string in a bash case statement

Tags: bash, case, numeric

I'm trying to match a string of 5 to 7 numbers in a case statement. Nothing I've tried successfully works. 
This is one of the things I tried.

```
^[0-9]*$ ) 
  echo "Got it!" 
  ;;
```

How do I do this successfully?

Comment: That's regular expression syntax, but a case statement takes glob-style pattern syntax.

Answer (score 7):

The patterns in a bash case statement are file globs, not regular expressions. Your best option may be an if/else chain instead of `case`:

```
if [[ "$string" =~ ^[0-9]{5,7}$ ]]; then
  echo "Got it!"
fi
```

However, if you are less picky about the exact length, you can use the extended glob feature to match "1 or more digits":

```
shopt -s extglob
case "$string" in
  (+([0-9])) echo "Got it!";;
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ isNum() { case $1 in (+([0-9])) echo 'Got it!' ;; esac; }
$ isNum 123A
$ isNum A123
$ isNum 1234
Got it!
```

If you want to also check length, that might be done separately:

```
isNum() {
  local len=${#1}
  if (( len < 5 || len > 7 )); then return; fi
  case $1 in (+([0-9])) echo 'Got it!' ;; esac
}
```

The trick here is "extglob" (extended glob) syntax, which allows functionality similar to proper regular expressions. `+(...)` in an extglob means "1 or more of ...".

See the bash-hackers page [Patterns and pattern matching](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) for details.

Except in ksh93, globs are not powerful enough to match a specific number of repetitions -- you need to actually write that out yourself. For instance:

```
# this is very clumsy, but works in all POSIX shells
isNum() {
  case $1 in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])           : "Matched 5" ;;
             [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])      : "Matched 6" ;;
             [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) : "Matched 7" ;;
             *) return ;;
  esac
  echo "Got it!" # only reached if the "return" didn't happen
}
```

Thus, you're probably better off using the bash-only regex syntax described in the answer by Mark Reed -- see also [the relevant bash-hackers page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression?s=regular%20expression).

Comment: If you don't need to *know* exactly how many characters matched, you should use the shorter (but still unwieldy) `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?([0-9]?([0-9]))`

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to use a `case` statement, then this would do the trick:

```
string=12345
case "${#string}-${string}" in
  5-[0-9]*)
    echo "'${string}' contains 5 digits"
    ;;
  7-[0-9]*)
    echo "'${string}' contains 7 digits"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Something else"
    ;;
esac
```

The idea is to count the characters and prepend the count to the number, so that the `case` string contains meta-data about the length in addition to the text itself.

Comment: But this would also match `1abcd`. Needs an extended glob to work: `5-+([0-9])`, for example.

Comment: This could be modified to provide an expensive, though POSIX-compatible, solution. Add `-$(echo "$string" | tr -d '[^0-9]')` to the string you are checking, then add `-"$string"` to each pattern. This  checks that the string itself is not modified by the act of deleting non-digit characters.